# Verify $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a}=1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is an exercise in Spivak's Calculus after the chapter on infinite sequences, so apparently he's asking to check that the sequence $\sqrt[n]{a}$ converges at 1.

First I was a bit surprised because $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a}=\lim_{n \to \infty}a^\frac1n=a^0=1$$

which is too easy. But the solutions manual says:

> Clearly $\lim_{n \to \infty}(\log{a})/n=0$. So $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a}=\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{(\log{a})/n}=e^0=1$ (by Theorem 1).

Theorem 1 says that if $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=l$ and $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence in the domain of $f$, $a_n\neq c, \lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=c$, then sequence $\{f(a_n)\}$ satisfies $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(a_n)=l$ and the converse is true.

Can I not treat limits of functions and sequences the same way? (I surely can since sequences are functions?).

Why go to the trouble of applying the theorem when the limit can be evaluated the way I did it, if it's correct at all?

Comment: It all depends on what can you base your assumptions and deductions. As easy as that. When I first learned this there were no functions, continuity or anything of the like at all. Just the basic algebra and limits stuff. So my proof is different. Spivak must be relying on stuff different from your and mine at that stage.

Comment: Well, your proof assumes you’ve proven $a^x$ is continuous at $x=0,$ while Spivak’s proof only uses $e^x$ is continuous at $x=0.$ But yes, if you know that $a^x$ is continuous, your proof is easier.

Comment: If you *don't* know yet that $a^x$ is continuous, Spivak's proof gives you a clue of how to apply continuity of $e^x$ to prove continuity of $a^x$, by making use of the defining formula $$a^x = e^{\log(a)  \cdot x}$$ *After* you've done that, then your proof is perfectly valid.

Comment: Also taking log is overkill here. Remember that this limit can be evaluated without taking log.

Comment: But this proof of the continuity of $a^x$ is not necessary, it’s obviously the exponential finction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof and Spivak’s proof use that $a^x$ and $e^x$ are continuous at $x=0,$ respectively. Perhaps Spivak didn’t want to assume that about $a^x$ yet?

There is a proof that doesn’t use any continuity.

We’ll prove for $a>1.$

Let $x_n=\sqrt[n]{a}-1>0.$

Then $a=(1+x_n)^n\geq 1+nx_n$ or $$0<x_n\leq \frac{a-1}{n}$$

By the squeeze theorem, $x_n\to 0,$ and hence $a^{1/n}=x_n+1\to 1.$

---

For $0<a<1$ we can just note that:

$$\sqrt[n]{a} =\frac1{\sqrt[n]{1/a}}$$

and apply the theorem for $1/a.$

---

This uses that:

> For $x\geq 0,$ and integer $n\geq 0,$ $$(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx$$

This is obviously true from the binomial theorem, but can easily be proven by induction without the full binomial theorem.

It is actually true for $x>-1.$ This is because $1+x>0$ so the induction step becomes:

$$\begin{align}(1+x)^{n+1}&\geq (1+nx)(1+x)\\&=1+(n+1)x+nx^2\\&\geq 1+(n+1)x\end{align}$$